# An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException' occurred in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll unexpected token 'part'

Tags: c#, python-3.x, ironpython

I am trying to run python script from c# using Ironpython but I get error like in title.

Here's the code part. It fails while importing in python

c#

```
                var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
                var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(templateLocation.Text + @"\test.py");
                var searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
                searchPaths.Add(templateLocation.Text+@"\Modules");
                engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
                List<String> argv = new List<String>();
                argv.Add(year.Text);
                argv.Add(filesLocation.Text);
                argv.Add(templateLocation.Text);
                argv.Add(reportLocation.Text);
                var scope = engine.CreateScope();
                engine.GetSysModule().SetVariable("argv", argv);
                source.Execute(scope);
```

Python

```
import sys
yearForm = sys.argv[0]
fileLocation = sys.argv[1].replace("\\","/")
exeLocation = sys.argv[2].replace("\\","/")
saveLocation = sys.argv[3].replace("\\","/")
sys.path.insert(1,exeLocation+"/Modules/")
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as cls
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from matplotlib.artist import setp
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import os
```

and let me just add that exeLocation is: C:\Users\Zlatko\name-annual-report

Comment: IronPython is not compatible with python 3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i could see, you cant execute this Python Script with ironpython: one reason is module Pandas for example, Pandas is pretty well tied to CPython.